# How do ORMs order commands to prevent constraint violations?

Tags: orm

Purely out of curiosity, I was hoping someone could explain how ORMs (like Hibernate or Entity Framework) determine the order that they need to execute SQL UPDATEs, INSERTs and DELETEs. Is there an algorithm for building up a topological dependency graph? Or do they cheat somehow and temporarily turn off constraints? Either way, a high-level explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to do a little research and then ask a more specific question. Just want to make sure we're not doing your homework.

Comment: If you use transactions you can tell the database to only check constraints when committing the transaction. (Called [*deferred foreign key constraints* in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_deferred). Not sure if that terminology is universal)

Comment: This is probably specific to each ORM. [There is an answer about Hibernate in StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22861675/147346). You should probably research the ORM you're interested in.

Comment: Databases typically check constraints in transaction commit, so any client, like an ORM  that wants multiple operations to be considered atomically wraps them in a db transaction.

Comment: Thanks guys. All of these comments are actually really useful. Short answer: it depends. These links are really helpful. Time to dig into some source code.